# Tinycad addon in Blender 2.92

Tags: mesh, add-on

I use Tinycad addon operations a lot in Blender, to my surprise, in Blender 2.92, even though I have Tinycad addon activated, it's no where to be found in the context menu in 3D View, as documentation suggests.
I select an object, switch to edit mode, then press <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for VTX or Tinycad, but I get irrelevant results, I thought this is a bug and reported it to the developer, but my report was closed with a reply "It's W or something now, report closed because there's nothing to be done"!, Well I tried the <kbd>W</kbd> which "now" it just switches the active selection tool, so does anyone knows what is the "something" that the developer was talking about? In other words, How can I use Tinycad in Blender 2.92, I tried all menus in Edit Mode, but perhaps I skipped something?
**Edit:** If you know of a replacement to Tinycad "That actually works in Blender 2.92" please post it as a comment.

Comment: Hello :). It's available through the right click context menu - would that work for you?

Comment: Oh, finally, I can't thank you enough, old Blender user here, right click in my brain is still firmly coupled to selection, I never use right click menu, please put this as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinyCAD is available through the <kbd>Right Click</kbd> context menu in Edit Mode.

[image]

Comment: Just a note: for those of us on the old keybindings with right-click select on, this menu is accessible by pressing [W].